# Installing CM10.2 - Stuck on Download Mode

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-s-3

I have a Galaxy SIII (GT-i9300) and I'm following the instructions for installing CyanogenMod on it [here](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Install_CM_for_i9300).

However, when following step 4 of the first part:

> 4. Boot the Galaxy S III (International) into download mode. Hold Home, Volume Down & Power. Accept the disclaimer on the device. Then, insert the USB cable into the device

I get stuck in the (in)famous `Downloading... Do not turn off target` screen. I don't even know if this is expected and if I should wait it to download something (download what? I have no idea). If this is not expected, what should I do to go on with the process?

I have checked other questions, but I couldn't tell if my case is the same, since other people state that they got into download mode by accident

Comment: Why are you installing CM10.2 from download mode. just use recovery mode

Comment: as far as I recall, I've always flashed my CM roms in recovery mode. then when the update feature came out, I just used that